# C# UWP Universal Windows App - Shape Resizing

Tags: c#, resize, uwp, shapes, viewbox

I'm working on an application that has a graphic editor. Aside from some other graphic components the main feature are some shapes (rectangles, triangles, stars etc.). The thing I would like to do is to have the ability to resize them after a double click, so there should be a container shown with points that can be dragged to resize the shape. There are many great tutorials out in the internet but mainly for rectangles or for other shapes that are "packed" into rectangle viewboxes.

The issue is that I need to have my resize points exactly on the vertexes, so for example I can't have a triangle inside a rectangle viewbox, but I need exactly three points - one on every vertex. The same applies for the other shapes like stars and arrows which are much more complicated.

Here's what I mean:

[image]

So I think I have two ways. Either pass a dynamic list of points after a double click and display them as separate shapes or binding them with my shape inside my shape class, but I cannot figure out how to add multiple shapes to a viewbox so that they keep their abilities. Here is a simplified snippet of how my shape classes look like:

```
 public class RectangleObject : ShapeObject
 {
    private Rectangle _rectangle;
    private Viewbox _viewbox;

    public RectangleObject(Color fillColor)
    {
        _rectangle = new Rectangle()
        {
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush(fillColor),
            Stretch = Stretch.Fill
        };

        _viewbox.child = _rectangle;
    }

    public void SetDimensions(){}

    //... and some other methods
 }
```

A nice solution would be if the viewbox could contain my shape and the resize points but I will appreciate any advice. I know that a canvas would be a better solution but all other components are packed in viewboxes so it would be problematic because of inheritance and would need many changes. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I know exactly what you mean.  I used *CorelDraw* back in the day and then *Adobe Illustrator* and both had the concept of **shape transformation** mode (your image on the right) as well as **vertex edit** mode (your image on the left).  UWP is similar to WPF and WPF has a concept of [adorners](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737(v=vs.110).aspx) which you can customise to do whatever you want including what I just described.

So when you enter one of these modes, rather than modify your existing shape to show selectors; instead you create adorners that are superimposed over the shape.  That way one doesn't clobber the other and you may have custom behavior for each as you indicated.

### See also

- *Adorners* - MSDN, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737(v=vs.110).aspx, retrieved 2017-1-12

Comment: Thank you very much, I am currently working on a solution using adorners, but it seems that in UWP adorners should be replaced by popups, but it's a very similar concept. Adorners exist in the PresentationFramework which is not used in UWP but only in WPF.

Comment: @losik123 Ah..no worries then.  Wishing you well